# Reading nested array in JSON AngularJs using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, android, json, angularjs

I am developing an Android application using angularjs and ionic framework, using JSON to display some data in the application front end. I want to generate HTML like this:

```
<span>name1</span>
<span>name2</span>
<span>name3</span>
```

Here is my JSON:

```
var items=[
        {name:["name1","name2","name3"]}        
    ];
```

I can read the JSON node by `myJsonObject.name`, but how can I iterate through the nested array?

Comment: Take a look at the official documentation of [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: i will tried ,but cant get the answer

Comment: There are examples in the documentation link.

Comment: Thats not help in my case

Comment: you need try something.. Show us what have you tried and what issue you faced?

Comment: I can read one element like this way `{{myJsonObject.name[0]}}` will output `name1`,but how can i itereate?

Comment: take a look at ng repeat documentation .

Comment: Can you show an example for me with my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To iterate over the nested array you would have to do something like the following:

```
<span ng-repeat="name in myJsonObject.name">{{name}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

- set value in angularjs 
  $scope.items=[
      {name:["name1","name2","name3"]}
  ];
- iterate in markup

  ```
  <span ng-repeat="name in items.0.name">{{ name }}</span>
  ```