# AngularJS Ng-repeat with array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have table and trying to render out table rows using the `ng-repeat`.

The situation is that I have a invoice which may or may not have multiple invoice details attached.  The data is returned in an object and one of those properties is an array.  So, I created my table and used `ng-repeat` using the array as the model.  In a way it works because three table rows are render out but the description remains field blank.

Thanks

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447063/reading-nested-array-in-json-angularjs-using-ng-repeat)

HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr style="cursor:pointer" ng-repeat="details in vm.orders.componetGrid ">                    
        <td ng-bind="details.componetGrid.componentDescription"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

JS

```
function loadOrder(invoiceNumber) {
    return orderService.getOrderById(invoiceNumber)
        .then(function (result) {
            vm.orders = result.data;                
        }, function (err) {
            console.log("error returned");
        });
}
```

sample of the data[image]

Comment: if you don't transform your data in between, details.componetGrid.componentDescription should be details.componentDescription

Comment: You are already referencing `vm.orders.componetGrid`as your `ng-repeat` array, you should use `details.componentDescription` in the iteration. I suggest that you correct the misspelled `componetGrid`, to `componentGrid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reference to componentDescription is wrong. This should work:

```
<tbody>
    <tr style="cursor:pointer" ng-repeat="details in vm.orders.componetGrid ">                    
        <td ng-bind="details.componentDescription"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

`details` is binded as each member of the `componetGrid`, so

```
                <td ng-bind="details.componetGrid.componentDescription"></td>
```

should be

```
                <td ng-bind="details.componentDescription"></td>
```

instead

Comment: I swore at one point I did have that.  Developing this in edge and doesnt always clear the cache but soon as I typed this back in worked.

Answer (score 1):

From the data you have provided in snippet it looks like componentgrid is a array.

Now in ng-repeat `details in vm.orders.componetGrid` means details is a componentgrid object.

So you should not say `details.componentgrid.componentDescription`

instead it should be `details.componentDescription`